# How to create DataFrame for filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This DataFrame is made up of the stock's asset, with its name in the 'asset' column. There are more than 80 assets in this column, but it's not visible. OK. Each asset has an Exponential Average per day in the MME column.

I need to create a new DataFrame where it shows me how many assets (a sum) are with the MME above the adjusted close of the day (Adj Close). So it would be a column showing the day, and another one on the side showing how many assets had this requirement.

Below is an image of the DataFrame at the moment:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about minimal reproduceable examples, it will help with future questions.

Comment: Your title should summarize the problem you are having. I have attempted to rewrite it to do so. Please edit it and correct it if it does not adequately capture what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive approach so that you can know how things are done.
First, you can take a copy of your existing dataframe so that the original one stays the same:

```
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
```

Then you can just convert your MME column to 1 which are greater than the "Adj Close" column values or else 0 so that it can be summed later on:

```
df1["MME"] = np.where((df["MME"]>df["Adj Close"]), 1, 0)
```

Then you can filter out the other unnecessary columns from this dataframe:

```
df1 = df1.filter(["Date", "MME"])
```

Then you need to group by the Date column to get the sum:

```
df1 = df1.groupby("Date").sum()
```